# Problem with focus event in chrome

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following script in my html page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var k_InitialTextBoxValue = "Please enter a cd name";

        function requestSuggestion(partialCdName) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Web1",
                data: "suggest=" + partialCdName,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }

        $("#textCdName").val(k_InitialTextBoxValue);

        $("#textCdName").focus(function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            /*if ($(this).val() == k_InitialTextBoxValue) {
                $(this).val() = "";
            }*/
        });


        $("#textCdName").keyup(function () {
            requestSuggestion($("#textCdName").val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everytime I focus the #textCdName text box element **once**, I got an infinite number of alert windows instead of one. This occurs in Chrome (v13), in IE it works fine.

Did this occure to anyone? how do I solve this issue?

Comment: If you replace the `alert` with a `console.log`, do you get only one message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes sense because when you throw an `alert`, the textbox loses focus (focus is now on the alert dialog).

When you dismist the alert box, the textbox gets focus once more, resulting in a new focus event firing and thus a new alert.

Instead of using an alert to debug your code, consider using `console.log` which adds the message to the console (you'll need a console viewer to see the messages, I'm not sure if there's one built in to Chrome).

```
console.log($(this).val());
```